# Android noHistory closes the Activity when request for permission

Tags: android, permissions

android:noHistory="true" closes the activity when permission is requested

How can I avoid closing of the activity on permission request?

Answer (score 1):

1. delete line `android:noHistory="true"` in Manifest file
2. In the activity, manage the permission
3. Move into the next activity with:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
```

Comment: If installed directly from Android Studio it works fine. But once download from play store and press the back button from main activity and launch the app again, login activity is called again.